# Show $\int \frac{\sin(x^p)}{x} dx = \frac{\operatorname{Si}(x)}{p} $

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, improper-integrals

I was messing around with the Fresnel integral and the Sine integral and found that $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(x^2)}{x}dx=\frac{\pi}{4}$ but I dont see how to extend to irrational powers.

Comment: This equality is wrong. You can see this most easily by differentiating.

Comment: The title mentions the indefinite integral, the corpus the definite one. Which one is it, really?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the substitution $y=x^p$, for $p>0$,
$$\int_0^\infty\sin(x^p)\frac{dx}{x}
=\int_0^\infty\sin(y)\frac{dy}{py}=\frac\pi{2p}.$$

Comment: This method gives the indefinite integral also